# unresolved external symbol __imp__free_dbg, __imp__malloc_dbg function

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi

Lot of question seem to be a duplicate, but this isn't. This was the .lib linking error, not the .obj linking error.

Error:

```
1>msvcprtd.lib(locale0_implib.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__free_dbg referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl std::_Fac_node::operator delete(void *)" (??3_Fac_node@std@@SAXPEAX@Z)
1>msvcprtd.lib(locale0_implib.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__malloc_dbg referenced in function "public: static void * __cdecl std::_Fac_node::operator new(unsigned __int64)" (??2_Fac_node@std@@SAPEAX_K@Z)
1>C:\Users\asdfs\source\repos\Debugger\x64\Debug\Debugger.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Code:
DebugLoop.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

DWORD OnCreateThreadDebugEvent(const LPDEBUG_EVENT);
DWORD OnCreateProcessDebugEvent(const LPDEBUG_EVENT);
DWORD OnExitThreadDebugEvent(const LPDEBUG_EVENT);
DWORD OnExitProcessDebugEvent(const LPDEBUG_EVENT);
DWORD OnLoadDllDebugEvent(const LPDEBUG_EVENT);
DWORD OnUnloadDllDebugEvent(const LPDEBUG_EVENT);
DWORD OnOutputDebugStringEvent(const LPDEBUG_EVENT);
DWORD OnRipEvent(const LPDEBUG_EVENT);
void EnterDebugLoop(const LPDEBUG_EVENT DebugEv);
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include "DebugLoop.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "Psapi.lib")
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    STARTUPINFOA si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    DEBUG_EVENT dbgEvent;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    ZeroMemory(&dbgEvent, sizeof(dbgEvent));
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s [cmdline]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // Start the child process. 
    if (!CreateProcessA(NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        argv[1],        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        )
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    if (WaitForDebugEventEx(&dbgEvent, INFINITE) > 0)
        EnterDebugLoop(&dbgEvent);

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

Command line:

Compiler:

```
/JMC /ifcOutput "x64\Release\" 
/GS /W1 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm- /Od
/Fd"x64\Release\vc143.pdb" 
/Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_MBCS" 
/errorReport:prompt /WX- 
/Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /FC 
/Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc 
/Fo"x64\Release\" /FAcs 
/Fp"x64\Release\Debugger.pch" 
/diagnostics:column
```

Linker:

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\asdfs\source\repos\Debugger\x64\Release\Debugger.exe" 
/MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT 
/PDB:"C:\Users\asdfs\source\repos\Debugger\x64\Release\Debugger.pdb" 
/DYNAMICBASE "msvcrtd.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" 
/DEBUG:FULL /MACHINE:X64 
/INCREMENTAL 
/PGD:"C:\Users\asdfs\source\repos\Debugger\x64\Release\Debugger.pgd" 
/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE 
/MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" 
/ManifestFile:"x64\Release\Debugger.exe.intermediate.manifest" 
/LTCGOUT:"x64\Release\Debugger.iobj"
/ERRORREPORT:PROMPT 
/ILK:"x64\Release\Debugger.ilk" 
/VERBOSE /TLBID:1
```

Comment: Change all your code+libraries CRT setting to either *with* DLL or *without* DLL in "Code Generation" in C++ options.

Comment: link with *ucrtd.lib*

Comment: It is also unusual to have `/MDd` ("Multi-threaded Debug DLL") as an option for a Release build

Comment: *This was the .lib linking error, not the .obj linking error.* Well, a ".lib" file is really just an archived bunch of ".obj" files. There are *some* subtle differences in how the linker handles the two but not that much.

Comment: Hmm. The [canonical duplicate target](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/10871073) for many of the "unresolved symbol" questions doesn't seem to have an answer for clashes between DLL/non-DLL and/or Debug/Release builds. Should one be added, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm forget the core libraries always needed to linked.

Just add the core library dependences (named `$(CoreLibraryDependencies)`) or inherit default values for `Additional Dependencies` field (for example that's the option was created by Visual Studio).

Or, this is the list of libraries needed to linked (for example, Release version):

- msvcrt.lib
- ucrt.lib
- ...

Comment: I'm glad you have got your solution and thank for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT Thanks, but I was found the solution after comparing to the `Debug` configuration.